# Spring batch job run infinitely

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to run spring batch job run infinitely. Main motive is that dont allow to spring batch sit idle

I am using below code to run job infinitely

```
private JobExecution execution = null;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
public void perform() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
    System.out.println("=== STATUS STARTED ====");

    if (execution != null && execution.isRunning()) {
        System.out.println("Job is running. Please wait.");
        return;
    }

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobId", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).addDate("date", new Date()).addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

    execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

    if (!execution.getStatus().isRunning()) {
        perform();
    }

    System.out.println("STATUS :: " + execution.getStatus());
}
```

First we are checking that JOB is running or not. If not running then we re-run the same method again. Now job is running infinitely.

My question is that is this approach is good or bad? Or any other solution?

> ```
> I have another query. If data is not available then break the infinite loop
> How to break that loop..
> ```

FYI, Below is the batch configuration code

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private Resource outputResource = new FileSystemResource("path\\output.csv");
    private Resource inputResource = new FileSystemResource("path\\input.csv");

    @Bean
    public ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner() {
        ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
        columnRangePartitioner.setColumn("id");
        columnRangePartitioner.setDataSource(dataSource);
        columnRangePartitioner.setTable("customer");
        return columnRangePartitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> pagingItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}") Long minValue, @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}") Long maxValue) {
        System.out.println("reading " + minValue + " to " + maxValue);
        // Create reader instance
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

        // Set input file location
        reader.setResource(inputResource);

        // Set number of lines to skips. Use it if file has header rows.
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);

        // Configure how each line will be parsed and mapped to different values
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {
            {
                // 3 columns in each row
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
                    }
                });
                // Set values in Employee class
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Customer>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Customer.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() {
        // Create writer instance
        FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

        // Set output file location
        writer.setResource(outputResource);

        // All job repetitions should "append" to same output file
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

        // Name field values sequence based on object properties
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Customer>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Customer>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return writer;
    }

    // Master
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), partitioner()).step(slaveStep()).gridSize(12).taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).build();
    }

    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep").<Customer, Customer>chunk(1000).reader(pagingItemReader(null, null)).writer(customerItemWriter()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(step1()).build();
    }
}
```

Another way for running step continuously

```
<job id="notificationBatchJobProcess"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        job-repository="jobRepository">

        <step id="startLogStep" next="execute">
            <tasklet ref="ref1" />
        </step>

        <step id="execute">
            <batch:tasklet ref="ref2" />
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="endLogStep" />
        </step>

        <step id="endLogStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="ref3" />
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="startLogStep" />
        </step>
    </job>
```

What I am trying to achieve using above code once endLogStep task is completed then again it will call startLogStep. 
And this process will continuing infinite time until or unless any exception is occurred.

Is this correct way for running those jobs?

Comment: `Main motive is that dont allow to spring batch sit idle`: Spring Batch does not sit idle by itself, it will run a job until completion (be it a success or failure) . It looks like you are running jobs in a JVM that is running all the time (may be a web app) and trying to maximise resource usage. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes... Correct.. I

Comment: ok, in that case, trying to run the job "infinitely" is not the way to keep a JVM busy. You still have to give the job something to do right? I recommend to extract your batch job out of the web app and run it in its own JVM on demand.

Comment: Job will run infinitely but if data is empty then we need to exits. Is there any workaround?